# Determine which member is visible in a namespace

Tags: c++

Consider the following Code Snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
namespace Foo {
    void bar() {
        std::cout<<"FOO::BAR"<<std::endl;
    }
}
namespace Spam {
    void bar() {
        std::cout<<"SPAM::BAR"<<std::endl;
    }
}
namespace fallbacks {
    using Foo::bar;
}

namespace Spam {
    using namespace fallbacks;
}

int main() {
    Spam::bar();
}
```

**Output**

```
SPAM::BAR
```

I understand that in this case, if Spam contains the member  it will refer to it. However if it doesn't , then the using directive's name will be found and refer to fallbacks::bar.

But I cannot find any authentic source to back the above statement.

Comment: I think you're being confused by ADL or something like that, Foo isn't used anywhere here nor fully qualified so Spam without bar will just cause an error

Comment: The question makes more sense if namespace `fallbacks` contains `using Foo::bar`, not `using Spam::bar`. Is this what was intended?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes my bad, that is what I intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Section 3.4.3** of the standard describes qualified name lookup. In particular, **section** **3.4.3.2** describes the lookup of namespace members.

> 3.4.3.2.2: For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the
>   namespace-qualified lookup set `S(X,m)` is defined as follows: Let
>   `S'(X,m)` be the set of all declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline
>   namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If `S'(X,m)` is not empty, `S(X,m)` is
>   `S'(X,m)`; otherwise, `S(X,m)` is the union of `S(N_i,m)` for all namespaces
>   `N_i` nominated by *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.

*(Source: ISO/IEC 14882:2011: C++ Standard)*

The following example is given:

```
int x;

namespace Y {
    void f(float);
    void h(int);
}

namespace Z {
    void h(double);
}

namespace A {
    using namespace Y;
    void f(int);
    void g(int);
    int i;
}

namespace B {
    using namespace Z;
    void f(char);
    int i;
}

namespace AB {
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
    void g();
}

void h()
{
    AB::g();  // g is declared directly in AB,
              // therefore S is { AB::g() } and AB::g() is chosen

    AB::f(1); // f is not declared directly in AB so the rules are
              // applied recursively to A and B;
              // namespace Y is not searched and Y::f(float)
              // is not considered;
              // S is { A::f(int), B::f(char) } and overload
              // resolution chooses A::f(int)

    AB::f(’c’); // as above but resolution chooses B::f(char)

    AB::x++;  // x is not declared directly in AB, and
              // is not declared in A or B , so the rules are
              // applied recursively to Y and Z,
              // S is { } so the program is ill-formed

    AB::i++;  // i is not declared directly in AB so the rules are
              // applied recursively to A and B,
              // S is { A::i , B::i } so the use is ambiguous
              // and the program is ill-formed

    AB::h(16.8); // h is not declared directly in AB and
                 // not declared directly in A or B so the rules are
                 // applied recursively to Y and Z,
                 // S is { Y::h(int), Z::h(double) } and overload
                 // resolution chooses Z::h(double)
}
```

*(Source: ISO/IEC 14882:2011: C++ Standard)*

In your example, if `Spam` contains `bar`, the set `S` contains `{Spam::bar}` and lookup stops. If the namespace `Spam` does not contain `bar`, any namespaces or `bar`s declared via `using` directives inside Spam will be searched, and this logic is applied recursively until either:

1. A namespace is found that contains `bar`, or
2. the possible search paths are exhausted, in which case the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding name look-up of qualified names is described in the following paragraphs of section 3.4.3.2 Namespace members of the C++ Standard

2 For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S0(X,m) be the set of all declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S0(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S0(X,m); otherwise, S(X,m) is the union of S(Ni,m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and its inline namespace set.

3 Given X::m (where X is a user-declared namespace), or given ::m (where X is the global namespace), if S(X,m) is the empty set, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(X,m) has exactly one member, or if the context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X,m) is the required set of declarations of m. Otherwise if the use of m is not one that allows a unique declaration to be chosen from S(X,m), the program is ill-formed.

In your case if to follow the quote "**Let S0(X,m) be the set of all declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S0(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S0(X,m);** " S( Spam, bar ) consists of one declaration of bar in Spam. And this declaration is the only declaration in Spam.  so this name will be found.